# Bootstrap Columns On Top Of Each Other on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on hhttp://pizzli.com/ephraimwp/employers/. When I view it on mobile, the two items in the sidebar overlap each other. Currently, I have the column nested within another column. Please see my code below and try viewing it on mobile:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:35px;">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0px;">

    <div id="innernav">
<?php
     $cat = get_field("sidebar_category");
if ($cat == 3){
    echo wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'aboutus'));
    }
elseif ($cat == 6){
    echo wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'employees'));
}
elseif ($cat ==5){
    echo wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'employers'));
}
elseif ($cat == 4){
    echo wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'ourservices'));
}
?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0px;">
                <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Inner Page 1 Left Sidebar')) : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <h2 class="titlehead"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <div  style="color:#a2a2a2;font-size:18px;">
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a demo fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a .col class to #innernav (col-md-8). I am just guessing the answer because you didn't provide a fiddle or bootply. it will be great if you can provide a fiddle for your question.